# Помогите с калькулятором стоимости перевозки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, калькулятор

очень долго разбирался для того чтобы сделать калькулятор стоимости перевозки в расчёте 2$ за милю, вроде почти получилось http://3d-craft.ru/car-calc.html, но считает маленько не точно, начинаю шаманить выдает кучу знаков после запятой(, но это ладно. Главное мне нужно понять как сделать, чтобы форма заказа после перерасчёта не дублировалась, а заменялась новой?

**Код**

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Стоимость за километр.
    var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 1.25,
    // Минимальная стоимость.
        MINIMUM_COST = 1,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [36.838093, -100.496856
],
            zoom: 5,
            controls: []
        }),
    // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                // Добавим заголовок панели.
    
                float: 'left',
                maxWidth: '500px',
                minWidth: '200px',
                showHeader: true,
                title: 'Delivery calculation'
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'large',
                float: 'right',
                position: {
                    top: 15,
                    right: 20
                }
            }
        });
    // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });

    // Если вы хотите задать неизменяемую точку "откуда", раскомментируйте код ниже.
    /*routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        fromEnabled: false,
        from: 'Москва, Льва Толстого 16'
     });*/

      myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

        // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
        route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

        // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
        route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

            var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
            if (activeRoute) {
                // Получим протяженность маршрута.
                var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance"),
                // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                    price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
                // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                    balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
      
                // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
    this.outputElement = $('<div><form id="feedback" action="mail.php" method="post"><p><div class="tt">Route length: </div><input name="length" value="' + length.text + '"></p><p><div class="tt">Delivery Price:  </div><input name="price" value="' + price + ' $"></p><p><div class="tt">Your Name:  </div><input type="text" name="name" value=""></p><p><div class="tt">Your Phone:  </div><input type="text" name="tel" value=""></p><p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p></div>').appendTo('#viewContainer');
      this.rebuildOutput();
                // Откроем балун.
                activeRoute.balloon.open();
            }
        });

    });
    // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
    function calculate(routeLength) {
        return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cost to ship a car</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="deliveryCalculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
   #map {
            width: 100%; height: 50%;
        }
        #viewContainer {
            margin: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
 <div id="viewContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Очищайте контейнер #viewContainer перед тем как вставлять туда данные.

Comment: это понятно вопрос как это реализовать в JS?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как решил вопрос)

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Стоимость за километр.
    var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 1.25,
    // Минимальная стоимость.
        MINIMUM_COST = 1,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [36.838093, -100.496856
],
            zoom: 5,
            controls: []
        }),
    // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                // Добавим заголовок панели.
    
                float: 'left',
                maxWidth: '500px',
                minWidth: '200px',
                showHeader: true,
                title: 'Delivery calculation'
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'large',
                float: 'right',
                position: {
                    top: 15,
                    right: 20
                }
            }
        });
    // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });

 

      myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

        // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
        route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

        // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
        route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

            var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
            if (activeRoute) {
                // Получим протяженность маршрута.
                var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance"),
                // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                    price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
                // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                    balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
      
                // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
                var d = document.getElementById("viewContainer");
while (d.firstChild)
    d.removeChild(d.firstChild);
    this.outputElement = $('<div><form id="feedback" action="mail.php" method="post"><p><div class="tt">Route length: </div><input name="length" value="' + length.text + '"></p><p><div class="tt">Delivery Price:  </div><input name="price" value="' + price + ' $"></p><p><div class="tt">Your Name:  </div><input type="text" name="name" value=""></p><p><div class="tt">Your Phone:  </div><input type="text" name="tel" value=""></p><p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p></div>').appendTo('#viewContainer');
      
                // Откроем балун.
                activeRoute.balloon.open();
            }
        });

    });
    // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
    function calculate(routeLength) {
        return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cost to ship a car</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="deliveryCalculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
   #map {
            width: 100%; height: 50%;
        }
        #viewContainer {
            margin: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
 <div id="viewContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```